# I get 'A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.' exception invoking Process.Start()

Tags: c#, cpu-architecture

Here is the code sample

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    Arguments = commandStr,
    FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\logman.exe",
};

using (var createCounterProc = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
{
    createCounterProc.Start();
    createCounterProc.WaitForExit();
}
```

After running the code I get "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process." message in MainModule (NativeErrorCode:299). My solution is configured to AnyCPU. I've tried both 64 and 32 bit versions of logman.exe (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\logman.exe and C:\Windows\System32\logman.exe) but I still have the same error. My OS is Win8.1Prox64. What could cause the problem?

Stack trace:

> ```
> at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
>    at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
>    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
> ```

Here is the Build configuration:

[image: build settings dialog]

Comment: have you tried changing you properties you run `x86 || x64`

Answer (score 25):

Choosing *Any CPU* for *Platform target* is not enough, you also have to uncheck *Prefer 32-bit*, otherwise the application will still be run as a 32-bit application.

[image]

This is only possible on application projects, not on library project. If your project is a library, you must do it in the project using your library.

Comment: I had an issue where the XAML designer would not execute my application code of design time view models when setting the application to x64. Then I switched it to Any CPU but had Win32Exceptions since I tried to access 64bit processes in my application **from a 32bit application**. You answer helped me to force 64bit on the respective machines and I haven't found anything else pointing to this option!

Comment: Just to add. Some projects has Prefer 32 bit unchecked but disabled.  E.g. Unit Tests projects. In such a case you also may have the exception.

Comment: For me, had to do it for both Release and Debug modes even though I was running just in Debiug mode.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation I realized that Logman.exe is unmanaged code, so it cannot return a .NET object as MainModule, so it's a normal behavior. I'ts just slightly confusing error message for Win32Exception. It doesn't influence the execution of Process.Start().

Comment: This is incorrect. MainModule returns a `ProcessModule` class. This class is a wrapper around basic Win32 calls which work with native constructs under the hood (this is in fact how most of the .Net APIs are implemented). So it doesn't matter what process you are inspecting you are ALWAYS getting a .Net wrapper around the native instance.