# A 32-bit process can not access modules in a 64-bit process

Tags: c#, memory, 64-bit

I'm trying to create a trainer for a game. Which causes a error (I think) because im trying to access the game memory of a 64 bit game with a 32 bit command.

Source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Infinite_Trainer___Cod_IW
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string prestigeLevel = bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue;
            string xp = bunifuSlider1.Value.ToString();
            string winrate = bunifuMaterialTextbox1.Text;
            string loserate = bunifuMaterialTextbox2.Text;

            Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("iw7_ship");
            if (process.Length > 0)
            {
                using (CheatEngine.Memory memory = new CheatEngine.Memory(process[0]))
                {
                    IntPtr prestigeAddress = memory.GetAddress("\"iw7_ship.exe\"+04105320+6E4");
                    memory.WriteUInt32(prestigeAddress, 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Game isn't running");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the memory.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Infinite_Trainer___Cod_IW.CheatEngine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an access to a remote process memory
    /// </summary>
    public class Memory : IDisposable
    {
        private Process process;
        private IntPtr processHandle;
        private bool isDisposed;

        public const string OffsetPattern = "(\\+|\\-){0,1}(0x){0,1}[a-fA-F0-9]{1,}";

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Memory
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="process">Remote process</param>
        public Memory(Process process)
        {
            if (process == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("process");

            this.process = process;
            processHandle = Win32.OpenProcess(
                Win32.ProcessAccessType.PROCESS_VM_READ | Win32.ProcessAccessType.PROCESS_VM_WRITE |
                Win32.ProcessAccessType.PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, true, (uint)process.Id);
            if (processHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not open the process");
        }

        #region IDisposable

        ~Memory()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (isDisposed)
                return;
            Win32.CloseHandle(processHandle);
            process = null;
            processHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            isDisposed = true;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the process to which this memory is attached to
        /// </summary>
        public Process Process
        {
            get
            {
                return process;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds module with the given name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Module name</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected ProcessModule FindModule(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
            foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
            {
                if (module.ModuleName.ToLower() == name.ToLower())
                    return module;
            }
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets module based address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="moduleName">Module name</param>
        /// <param name="baseAddress">Base address</param>
        /// <param name="offsets">Collection of offsets</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IntPtr GetAddress(string moduleName, IntPtr baseAddress, int[] offsets)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(moduleName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("moduleName");

            ProcessModule module = FindModule(moduleName);
            if (module == null)
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            else
            {
                int address = module.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + baseAddress.ToInt32();
                return GetAddress((IntPtr)address, offsets);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="baseAddress">Base address</param>
        /// <param name="offsets">Collection of offsets</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IntPtr GetAddress(IntPtr baseAddress, int[] offsets)
        {
            if (baseAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid base address");

            int address = baseAddress.ToInt32();

            if (offsets != null && offsets.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
                foreach (int offset in offsets)
                    address = ReadInt32((IntPtr)address) + offset;
            }

            return (IntPtr)address;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets address pointer
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Address</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IntPtr GetAddress(string address)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("address");

            string moduleName = null;
            int index = address.IndexOf('"');
            if (index != -1)
            {
                // Module name at the beginning
                int endIndex = address.IndexOf('"', index + 1);
                if (endIndex == -1)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid module name. Could not find matching \"");
                moduleName = address.Substring(index + 1, endIndex - 1);
                address = address.Substring(endIndex + 1);
            }

            int[] offsets = GetAddressOffsets(address);
            int[] _offsets = null;
            IntPtr baseAddress = offsets != null && offsets.Length > 0 ?
                (IntPtr)offsets[0] : IntPtr.Zero;
            if (offsets != null && offsets.Length > 1)
            {
                _offsets = new int[offsets.Length - 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < offsets.Length - 1; i++)
                    _offsets[i] = offsets[i + 1];
            }

            if (moduleName != null)
                return GetAddress(moduleName, baseAddress, _offsets);
            else
                return GetAddress(baseAddress, _offsets);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets address offsets
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Address</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        protected static int[] GetAddressOffsets(string address)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(address))
                return new int[0];
            else
            {
                MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(address, OffsetPattern);
                int[] offsets = new int[matches.Count];
                string value;
                char ch;
                for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
                {
                    ch = matches[i].Value[0];
                    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-')
                        value = matches[i].Value.Substring(1);
                    else
                        value = matches[i].Value;
                    offsets[i] = Convert.ToInt32(value, 16);
                    if (ch == '-')
                        offsets[i] = -offsets[i];
                }
                return offsets;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads memory at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <param name="buffer">Buffer</param>
        /// <param name="size">Size in bytes</param>
        public void ReadMemory(IntPtr address, byte[] buffer, int size)
        {
            if (isDisposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("Memory");
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
            if (size <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Size must be greater than zero");
            if (address == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid address");

            uint read = 0;
            if (!Win32.ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, (uint)size, ref read) ||
                read != size)
                throw new AccessViolationException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes memory at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <param name="buffer">Buffer</param>
        /// <param name="size">Size in bytes</param>
        public void WriteMemory(IntPtr address, byte[] buffer, int size)
        {
            if (isDisposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("Memory");
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
            if (size <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Size must be greater than zero");
            if (address == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid address");

            uint write = 0;
            if (!Win32.WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, address, buffer, (uint)size, ref write) ||
                write != size)
                throw new AccessViolationException();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads 32 bit signed integer at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int ReadInt32(IntPtr address)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            ReadMemory(address, buffer, 4);
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads 32 bit unsigned integer at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public uint ReadUInt32(IntPtr address)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            ReadMemory(address, buffer, 4);
            return BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads single precision value at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public float ReadFloat(IntPtr address)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
            ReadMemory(address, buffer, 4);
            return BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads double precision value at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public double ReadDouble(IntPtr address)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
            ReadMemory(address, buffer, 8);
            return BitConverter.ToDouble(buffer, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes 32 bit unsigned integer at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void WriteUInt32(IntPtr address, uint value)
        {
            byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
            WriteMemory(address, buffer, 4);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes 32 bit signed integer at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void WriteInt32(IntPtr address, int value)
        {
            byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
            WriteMemory(address, buffer, 4);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes single precision value at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void WriteFloat(IntPtr address, float value)
        {
            byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
            WriteMemory(address, buffer, 4);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes double precision value at the address
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Memory address</param>
        /// <param name="value">Value</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void WriteDouble(IntPtr address, double value)
        {
            byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
            WriteMemory(address, buffer, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly I'm receiving the following error code:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll


Additional information: A 32-bit process can not access modules in a 64-bit process.
```

This error should be caused by the following line: `memory.WriteUInt32(prestigeAddress, 1);`

Does anyone know what I could do now or if there's a fix for this? Or do I need a whole new Memory Processing class?

I would appreciate any kind of help

**UPDATE**

The new error does look like the following:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The arithmetic operation has caused an overflow.
```

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/04107c28a4d7af0599f1dd59c72b6020

Full log:

```
System.OverflowException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233066
  Message=The arithmetic operation caused an overflow.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.IntPtr.ToInt32()
       at Infinite_Trainer___Cod_IW.CheatEngine.Memory.GetAddress(String moduleName, IntPtr baseAddress, Int32[] offsets) in C:\Users\d4ne\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Infinite Trainer - Cod IW\Infinite Trainer - Cod IW\CheatEngine\Memory.cs:Line 109.
       at Infinite_Trainer___Cod_IW.Form1.bunifuFlatButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\d4ne\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Infinite Trainer - Cod IW\Infinite Trainer - Cod IW\Form1.cs:Line 40.
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Infinite_Trainer___Cod_IW.Program.Main() in C:\Users\d4ne\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Infinite Trainer - Cod IW\Infinite Trainer - Cod IW\Program.cs:Line 19.
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check out this[32 bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070969/i-get-a-32-bit-processes-cannot-access-modules-of-a-64-bit-process-exception)

Could be your project is targeting 32 instead of 64 bit?

Comment: 'Memory' does not contain a definition for 'WriteUInt64' and no extension method 'WriteUInt64' accepting a first argument of type 'Memory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) So there's no function inside the class like this

Comment: @user2452165 please see updated answer. I think this should resolve it

Comment: https://gyazo.com/a444f47cf263e8c849435c6224c82e70 checking the rest rn

Comment: @user2452165 hmmm there should be a different window that matches up like in the thread I linked. I believe it's when you right click the project in solution explorer and go to properties. There should be more options than the screencapture you shared

Comment: Yes i found that overview and it got me further, getting a new error now but your answer fixed my main issue :) Thank you!

Comment: @user2452165 feel free to post what the new error as an edit instead of making a new question (up to you). I'll try to help as much as I can. Also thanks for accepting my answer (I would appreciate an upvote if it helped :D )

Comment: @user2452165 I'm looking at this on my phone did it specify a line?

Comment: Line 109 in the memory class this is the code: int address = module.BaseAddress.ToInt32() + baseAddress.ToInt32();
                return GetAddress((IntPtr)address, offsets);

Comment: @user2452165 can module and baseaddress be used with toint64?