# Failing Unit Test Only On My Local Machine But Others Computers They Are Passing? Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, dll, nuget, specflow

Beginner here

One of my solutions on my local machine are now failing several unit tests.

I have since moved onto the production branch (where all unit tests are confirmed to be working) but they are still failing for some reason.

I have tried to:

- Delete local copy of branch and re-pull from remote repository
- Clean, rebuild solution
- Deleted all bin and obj folders + clean and rebuild
- Restarted visual studio and laptop
- Re-cloned entire repository

These unit tests appear to be working on other peoples local machine.

Some of the exceptions appear to be OneTimeSetUpExceptions.Others appear to be string result is different from the expected result.

EDIT: I get this error when running the tests:

```
ERROR: Could not find out Visual Studio version: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.
```

EDIT: I had also previously been renaming some folders in Visual Studio but has since recloned the repository so that should be a problem? It said it will relink the test files after I renamed it so not sure if that did something.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: Things you may want to check are the target processor architecture (x86 vs x64) that could lead to numerical differences. String handling may depend on the local culture which is local to your machine. Apart from some specific failure results it remains a guess what the cause is. Heck, we've even had differences between WIndows and Linux builds on sorting.

Comment: @Paul Thanks! You're right, it was something to do with x86 vs x64. I've just rerun the tests with Platform target to Any Cpu. Hoping for good result

Comment: EDIT:  I've just rerun the tests with solution config to build "AnyCpu" and Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects at x64. Still failing tests.

Comment: Can you provide an example to help reproduce the problem? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34071226/17296043) can help you?

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Thanks for the link. I was able to run the test without the errors popping up but still failing tests. It's a bit hard to reproduce the problem since it's only on my machine but working on others :/

Comment: How about this? [Run a unit test as a 64-bit process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/run-a-unit-test-as-a-64-bit-process)

Comment: PARTIAL SOLUTION: UPDATE some unit tests that were failing from incorrect dates would be fixed via changing the date configuration on my laptop. Some of the other unit tests that had some sort of setup failure could pass when running the test individually.